# HTTP 503 Error occurs when I use script. Manul dont

Tags: python, http-error

I wrote script in Python, which send requests to google and make something with results.
I used gogole library, which I found somewhere in Internet :)
When I requested many times ( aprox. 50) Google blocks another requests(503 Error), regardless time.sleep(2) in every iteration.

Above google library uses urllib and BeautifulSoup. Do you know what can make errors or maybe do you know what library is better?

Tomek

Comment: Google doesn't like automated queries.

Comment: probably there are limitations on the number of requests per time (rate limit) and you hit that.

Comment: So what is a time between requests which I should set in time.sleep()?